# BigQuery: error to fetch query results from PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I've changed some configurations on BigQuery and actually I can't fetch data anymore.

This is the flow:

```
  $query = "select what i need to select";
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Google-BigQuery');
  $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); // running in app engine env
  $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery');
  $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write');
  $bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
  $job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
  $config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
  $queryConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationQuery();
  $config->setQuery($queryConfig);
  $job->setConfiguration($config);
  $queryConfig->setQuery($query);
```

Then:

```
$job = $bq->jobs->insert($project, $job); // OK
$jr = $job->getJobReference(); // OK -> here i got jobid as $jr['jobId']
$queryResults =  $bq->jobs->getQueryResults('my-project', 'job-id-from-jr'); // ERROR
```

If I run the query from BigQuery dashboard, it's work and I can get results.
Here I got a 404 error, "notfound", I've checked if the job id match with that on the dashboard, and it match.
{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Not found: Job my-project:job-id",

The only one difference is that on the job inside the dashboard is specified the location as

> my-name:europe-west1.job-id

Can't find a way to specify directly the zone of execution, I've tried to add europe-west1 as a string before job-id, but got error about that (it can't be done).

There is a way to fix this? It's possible to specify the zone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved by passing an array as 3rd parameter

```
$arrLocation = array("location" => "europe-west1");
$queryResults =  $bq->jobs->getQueryResults('my-project', 'job-id-from-jr', $arrLocation);
```